# Qt/VTK: Access functions in custom interactor class

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I have a Qt GUI called MainWindow.

I am rendering some 3D objects in the constructor of the `MainWindow`.
Moreover I declared a custom class of the `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera` in *MainWindow.cpp* like in [this example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/MouseEvents).

Now I would like to call a function from the `MainWindow` class in the function `OnLeftButtonDown()` from my custom class of the Interactor.

I tried to inherit the `MainWindow` class to the custom Interactor class like this:

```
class customMouseInteractorStyle : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera, MainWindow
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I access the functions of the `MainWindow` there?

The function is automatically called when pressing the left button of the mouse.

```
// Define interaction style
class customMouseInteractorStyle : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
{
public:
    static customMouseInteractorStyle* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(customMouseInteractorStyle,     vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);

    virtual void OnRightButtonDown()
    {
        MainWindowfunction();    // <- I want to call this
        vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnRightButtonDown();
    }

};

vtkStandardNewMacro(customMouseInteractorStyle);


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
      // Rendering some things
}

void MainWindow::MainWindowfunction
{
// Do something
}
```

Comment: Is the `OnLeftButtonDown()` called in another thread?

Comment: Also, you should show your `OnLeftButtonDown()` method's code. And "this doesn't work" is a very poor error description, what do you mean exactly? You can't get it to compile? It crashes? What?

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I added some code, hope this helps to understand my problem.
It does not work means that I can compile but not debug (the window doesn't open and everything gets slow). Sorry for the inaccurate description

Comment: When you construct the custom class, pass a pointer or reference to the MainWindow to the constructor and store it as a class member variable. Then you can call public functions on the MainWindow from anywhere inside the custom class.

Comment: Thank you!! 
How can I store it as a class member variable? (sry I am new to C++)

Comment: I changed the constructor like this:

 customMouseInteractorStyle(MainWindow *ptr)
 {
  ptr->MainWindowfunction();
 }

Now I can access the function in the constructor, but I want access this function in the whole custom interactor class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question, so you say you have this constructor:

```
customMouseInteractorStyle(MainWindow *ptr) { ptr->MainWindowfunction(); }
```

To make this work, first add a member variable:

```
private:
    MainWindow *mainWin;
```

Then change the constructor to initialize it:

```
customMouseInteractorStyle(MainWindow *ptr) : mainWin(ptr) {}
```

Then your `OnRightButtonDown` becomes:

```
virtual void OnRightButtonDown()
{
    mainWin->MainWindowfunction();
    vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnRightButtonDown();
}
```